# How to use CSS property position:fixed with top:50px and height:100%?

Tags: css, css-position

I am trying to get a div with property

```
position:fixed;
```

to stretch the entire height of the page and scroll vertically if necessary, but also include an offset from the top of the page by using

```
top:50px;
bottom:0;
```

The div is displaying beneath the bottom of the page. I would like the div and scrollbar to end at the bottom of the page and not continue to display off the page. If I set div property top:0, it works fine, but I need the 50px offset from the top of the page. My page code is shown below:

```
<style>
    .container1
    {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        width:100px;
        top:50px;
        bottom:0;
    }
    .content
    {
        height:2000px;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could anybody help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question, you can just use calc on you height, so you change the height to:

```
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

Comment: to stretch the entire height of the page and scroll vertically if necessary?? really ??

Comment: Year i have usally succes with that method?

Answer (score 2):

For that you must use  `position: absolute;`

```
.container1
    {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        width:100px;
        top:50px;
        bottom:0;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T7JS5/)

Answer (score 0):

try to add at .container1

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the

```
height: 100%;
```

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/frankenscarf/MRMws/)